# Compile time error with Spring Data and JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

By using Spring Data, I'm developing a java project that defines rules, repositories and services in order to perform data access following the JPA specifications.

This is my source code:

**DALConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "my.project.dal" })
@PropertySource("classpath:dbconnection.properties")
@EnableJpaRepositories("my.project.dal.repository")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class DALConfig {

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER = "db.driver_class";  
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD = "db.password";  
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL = "db.url";  
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME = "db.username";  

    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_POOL_INITIAL_SIZE = "pool.initialsize";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_POOL_MAX_IDLE = "pool.maxidle";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_DAL_CLASSES_PACKAGE = "entities.packages_to_scan";  
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT = "hibernate.dialect";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL = "hibernate.showsql";
    private static final String PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL = "hibernate.format_sql";

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;  

    /**
     * Method which handles the <i>dataSource</i> bean creation.
     * @return Returns a {@link DataSource} class instance which connects to the PRISMA platform DB.
     */ 
    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() {
        Properties props = new Properties();

        props.put("driverClassName", environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_DRIVER));
        props.put("url", environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_URL));
        props.put("username", environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_USERNAME));
        props.put("password", environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DATABASE_PASSWORD));
        props.put("initialSize", environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_POOL_INITIAL_SIZE));
        props.put("maxIdle", environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_POOL_MAX_IDLE));

        BasicDataSource bds = null;
        try {
            bds = BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(props);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bds;
    }

    /**
     * Method which handles the <i>persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor</i> bean creation.
     * @return Returns a {@link PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor} class instance.
     */ 
    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor() {
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }   

    /**
     * Method which handles the <i>hibernateExceptionTranslator</i> bean creation.
     * @return Returns a {@link HibernateExceptionTranslator} class instance which manages the Hibernate Exceltions translation into Spring's ones.
     */ 
    @Bean 
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator(){ 
      return new HibernateExceptionTranslator(); 
    }

    /**
     * Method which handles the <i>transactionManager</i> bean creation.
     * @return Returns a {@link PlatformTransactionManager} class instance.
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException
     */ 
    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getObject());
        return transactionManager;
    }

    /**
     * Method which handles the <i>entityManagerFactory</i> bean creation.
     * @return Returns a {@link LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean} class instance.
     * @throws ClassNotFoundException
     */ 
    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws ClassNotFoundException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_DAL_CLASSES_PACKAGE));
        entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);

        Properties jpaProperties = new Properties();
        jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT, environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_DIALECT));
        jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL, environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_FORMAT_SQL));
        jpaProperties.put(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL, environment.getRequiredProperty(PROPERTY_NAME_HIBERNATE_SHOW_SQL));

        entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaProperties);

        return entityManagerFactoryBean;
    }

}
```

**IUserRepository:**

```
@Repository
public interface IUserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, String> { }
```

**UserService:**

```
@Service
public class UserService {

    @Autowired
    private IUserRepository repository;

    @PersistenceContext
    EntityManager em;

    /**
     * Method which finds a {@link User} by the provided <i>username</i>.
     * 
     * @param username
     *            The username of the {@link User} to be found.
     * @return Returns the found {@link User}.
     * @throws DataRetrievalFailureException
     *             If the User doesn't exist in the DB.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             If the <i>username</i> is <i>null</i>
     */
    public User find(String username) throws DataRetrievalFailureException,
            IllegalArgumentException {
        User user = repository.findOne(username);
        if (user == null)
            throw new DataRetrievalFailureException("User with username = \""
                    + username + "\" not found");
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Method which inserts the provided {@link User}.
     * 
     * @param user
     *            The {@link User} to be inserted.
     * @return Returns the inserted {@link User}. Use the returned instance for
     *         further operations as the insert operation might have changed the
     *         entity instance completely.
     * @throws DuplicateKeyException
     *             If the <i>user</i> already exists in the DB.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             If the username of the <i>user</i> is <i>null</i>
     * @throws JpaSystemException
     *             If a unique field is already in the DB.
     */
    public User insert(User user) throws DuplicateKeyException,
            JpaSystemException {
        if (repository.exists(user.getUsername()))
            throw new DuplicateKeyException("User with username = \""
                    + user.getUsername() + "\" already exists");
        return repository.save(user);
    }

    /**
     * Method which deletes the {@link User} identifiedy by <i>username</i>.
     * 
     * @param username
     *            The username of the {@link User} to be deleted.
     * @throws EmptyResultDataAccessException
     *             If a {@link User} with the provided <i>username</i> doesn't
     *             exist in the DB.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             If the <i>username</i> is <i>null</i>
     */
    public void delete(String username) throws EmptyResultDataAccessException,
            IllegalArgumentException {
        repository.delete(username);
    }

    /**
     * Method which updates the provided {@link User} <i>user</i> in the DB.
     * 
     * @param user
     *            The updated {@link User}.
     * @return Returns the updated {@link User}. Use the returned instance for
     *         further operations as the insert operation might have changed the
     *         entity instance completely.
     * @throws DataRetrievalFailureException
     *             If the <i>user</i> doesn't exist in the DB.
     * @throws IllegalArgumentException
     *             If the username of the <i>user</i> is <i>null</i>
     */
    public User update(User user) throws DataRetrievalFailureException {
        if (!repository.exists(user.getUsername()))
            throw new DataRetrievalFailureException("User with username = \""
                    + user.getUsername() + "\" not found");
        return repository.save(user);
    }
}
```

By using Maven, I generated the jar and then I added it to another Spring boot project.

At compile time, it returns this error:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: it.project.dal.service.UserService it.project.businesslayer.UserManagement.userService; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private it.project.dal.repository.IUserRepository it.project.dal.service.UserService.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'IUserRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#2c19cee5' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2c19cee5': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [it/project/dal/config/DALConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 106 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'userService': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private it.project.dal.repository.IUserRepository it.project.dal.service.UserService.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'IUserRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#2c19cee5' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2c19cee5': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [it/project/dal/config/DALConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:292)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1185)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 108 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire field: private it.project.dal.repository.IUserRepository it.project.dal.service.UserService.repository; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'IUserRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#2c19cee5' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2c19cee5': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [it/project/dal/config/DALConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:508)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:87)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    ... 119 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'IUserRepository': Cannot create inner bean '(inner bean)#2c19cee5' of type [org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator] while setting bean property 'entityManager'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2c19cee5': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [it/project/dal/config/DALConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:290)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:129)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:537)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.findAutowireCandidates(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1017)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:858)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:480)
    ... 121 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#2c19cee5': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [it/project/dal/config/DALConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:336)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:632)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:442)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1094)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:989)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:276)
    ... 134 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [it/project/dal/config/DALConfig.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:539)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:304)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:300)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:195)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:328)
    ... 142 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode;
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.PersistenceUnitInfoDescriptor.getValidationMode(PersistenceUnitInfoDescriptor.java:99)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.mergePropertySources(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:567)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:212)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.<init>(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:45)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.spi.Bootstrap.getEntityManagerFactoryBuilder(Bootstrap.java:57)
    at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:150)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
    ... 149 common frames omitted
```

How can I fix this error?

**Note:** entity classes are in another project.

Comment: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.persistence.spi.PersistenceUnitInfo.getValidationMode()Ljavax/persistence/ValidationMode got the right version of whatever jar that depends on

Comment: <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
   <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.2</version>
  </dependency>

Answer (score 2):

change your `javax.persistance` dependecy  to

```
    <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
             <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency

getValidationMode() exists only in JPA 2
```